# SNMP4J getting and setting values

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I need to get and set a few values by SNMP v2.  I'm looking for simple example of code which using SNMP4J (or any another library) to get and set values by OIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many over the internet:

1. Previous Question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224687/getting-started-with-snmp4j)
2. http://blog.jayway.com/2010/05/21/introduction-to-snmp4j/

This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for useful links. I guess I'm ready to use SNMP now.

Comment: Glad to know that, kindly accept answer as correct is you feel so :)

Answer (score 4):

I have written a simple application using snmp4j.jar and java. I have mentioned how to test this application by enabling snmp agent running on your windows machine as well.

A simple application is given [here](http://programming-x.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-get-started-with-snmp4j.html)