# Need support: SNMP trap sender (SNMPv3)

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmp-trap, snmptrapd

Can someone help me in creating an agent which can send SNMPv3 traps to NMS?
Open to use SNMP4J or net-snmp.

Comment: Please don't ask this kind of open-ended question on StackOverflow. This looks like you are asking us to design your software for you, which is not the purpose of SO. Please read the guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then edit your question to adhere to the format of the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SNMPv3 supports authentication and privacy among other new features, making it more secure and a little more complicated to implement as compared to the previous versions. The Network Management System(NMS) can support multiple configurations.

1. No Authorization and No Privacy - Least Secure.
2. Authorization and No Privacy - Not immune to attack from intruders.
3. Authorization with Privacy - Most Secure.

Note: No Authorization and Privacy is not supported.

Based on the supported configuration of the NMS, you can create the SNMP agent. You can check out my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224687/getting-started-with-snmp4j/45971750#45971750) which explains how to create a SNMPv3 agent with Authorization and Privacy. If you want don't want authorization and privacy in your SNMP agent, you can simply remove the USM entries.